# Exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms, density-function, exponential-distribution

I am stucking on this problem from days, I need help, if anyone could help me.
I have $Y=\log(1+X)$ with $X$ that follows an exponential distribution, I would understand which is the $Y$ distribution, is $Y$ also exponential?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? How is the cumulative distribution functions defined?

Answer (score 2):

No. If $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, the CDF of $Y$ is$$P(Y\le y)=P(X\le\exp y-1)=1-\exp(-\lambda(\exp y-1))$$for $y\ge0$. This is a [Gompertz distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_distribution) with $\eta=\lambda,\,b=1$.